# Combinar RowFilter.andFilter com RowFilter.orFilter

Tags: java, swing, jtable, rowfilter

Tenho um projeto que possui uma tabela e itens para serem filtrados. São eles uma categoria`JComboBox`, um id `JTextField` e um intervalo de data `JDateCooser`.

Fiz todos os filtros separadamente com `RowFilter.andFilter` e agora preciso juntá-los em um `RowFilter.orFilter` para que qualquer um possa acontecer a qualquer momento.

Eu preciso que seja possível filtrar os dados da tabela usando diferentes combinações de campos preenchidos:

> - categoria, nome e intervalo de data simultâneamente (filtrosAnd)
> - somente categoria (filtroCateg)
> - somente nome (filtroId, sim o nome é esse mesmo)
> - somente o intervalo de data (filtroData)
> - nome e intervalo de data simultâneamente (filtroIdData)
> - categoria e nome simultâneamente (filtroIdCateg)
> - categoria e intervalo de data simultâneamente (filtroDatacateg)

Todos eles precisam ser possíveis de acontecer de acordo com o que o usuário do programa decidir preencher na hora de pressionar o botão filtrar.

Representando categoria por C, nome por N e intervalo de data por D o que eu preciso que aconteça ficaria assim:

`((C && N && D) || (C) || (N) || (D) || (N && D) || (C && N) || (C && D))`

Filtros

```
    import java.awt.Dimension;
    import java.util.Date;
    import java.util.HashSet;
    import java.util.Set;
    import javax.swing.JButton;
    import javax.swing.JScrollBar;
    import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
    import javax.swing.RowFilter;
    import javax.swing.RowFilter.ComparisonType;
    import javax.swing.table.TableModel;
    import javax.swing.table.TableRowSorter;


    public class Filtros extends javax.swing.JFrame {

        private final int ITENS_POR_PAG = 5;

        public Filtros() {
            initComponents();
        }

        private void initComponents() {

            jScrollPane = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
            table = new javax.swing.JTable();
            btnFirst = new javax.swing.JButton();
            btnPrevious = new javax.swing.JButton();
            btnNext = new javax.swing.JButton();
            btnLast = new javax.swing.JButton();
            lblCategoria = new javax.swing.JLabel();
            cbxCategoria = new javax.swing.JComboBox<>();
            jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
            txtNome = new javax.swing.JTextField();
            btnFiltrar = new javax.swing.JButton();
            lblDataDeInicio = new javax.swing.JLabel();
            jdcDataDeInicio = new com.toedter.calendar.JDateChooser();
            lblDataDeFim = new javax.swing.JLabel();
            jdcDataDeFim = new com.toedter.calendar.JDateChooser();

            setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

            jdcDataDeInicio.setDateFormatString("dd/MM/yyyy");
            jdcDataDeFim.setDateFormatString("dd/MM/yyyy");

            model = new MatriculaTableModel(JSONUtils.JSONtoList());
            table.setModel(model);
            sorter = new TableRowSorter<TableModel>(model);
            table.setRowSorter(sorter);   
            table.setDefaultRenderer(Date.class, new MatriculaTableRenderer());

            jScrollPane = new JScrollPane(table, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER,
                    JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
            jScrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(getPreferredSize().width - 20, table.getRowHeight() * ITENS_POR_PAG + table.getTableHeader().getPreferredSize().height));

            jScrollPane.setViewportView(table);


            btnFirst = new JButton("<<");
            btnFirst.addActionListener(e -> {
                JScrollBar bar = jScrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar();
                bar.setValue(0);
            });

            btnPrevious = new JButton("<");
            btnPrevious.addActionListener(e -> {
                int height = table.getRowHeight() * (ITENS_POR_PAG);
                JScrollBar bar = jScrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar();
                bar.setValue(bar.getValue() - height);
            });

            btnNext = new JButton(">");
            btnNext.addActionListener(e -> {
                int height = table.getRowHeight() * (ITENS_POR_PAG);
                JScrollBar bar = jScrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar();
                bar.setValue(bar.getValue() + height);
            });

            btnLast = new JButton(">>");
            btnLast.addActionListener(e -> {
                JScrollBar bar = jScrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar();
                bar.setValue(bar.getMaximum());
            });

            btnFiltrar.addActionListener(e -> {
                aplicaFiltros();
            });

            lblCategoria.setText("Categoria");

            cbxCategoria.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel<>(new String[] { "Todas", "Fundamental", "Médio" }));

            jLabel1.setText("Nome:");

            btnFiltrar.setText("Filtrar");

            lblDataDeInicio.setText("De:");

            lblDataDeFim.setText("Até:");

            javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
            getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
            layout.setHorizontalGroup(
                layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                    .addGap(94, 94, 94)
                                    .addComponent(btnFirst)
                                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                    .addComponent(btnPrevious)
                                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                    .addComponent(btnNext)
                                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                    .addComponent(btnLast))
                                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                    .addContainerGap()
                                    .addComponent(lblDataDeInicio)
                                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                    .addComponent(jdcDataDeInicio, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 150, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                    .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                                    .addComponent(lblDataDeFim)
                                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                    .addComponent(jdcDataDeFim, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 150, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                            .addGap(0, 16, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addComponent(lblCategoria)
                            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                            .addComponent(cbxCategoria, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 100, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                            .addComponent(jLabel1)
                            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                            .addComponent(txtNome)
                            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                            .addComponent(btnFiltrar)))
                    .addContainerGap())
            );
            layout.setVerticalGroup(
                layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(jScrollPane, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 176, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(btnFirst)
                        .addComponent(btnPrevious)
                        .addComponent(btnNext)
                        .addComponent(btnLast))
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 21, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(cbxCategoria, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(lblCategoria)
                        .addComponent(jLabel1)
                        .addComponent(txtNome, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(btnFiltrar))
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addComponent(lblDataDeInicio)
                        .addComponent(jdcDataDeInicio, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(lblDataDeFim)
                        .addComponent(jdcDataDeFim, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 20, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGap(20, 20, 20))
            );

            pack();
        }// </editor-fold>               

            public static void main(String args[]) {
            /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
            //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
            /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
             * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
             */
            try {
                for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                    if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                        javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                        break;
                    }
                }
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Filtros.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
                java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Filtros.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
                java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Filtros.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Filtros.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            //</editor-fold>

            /* Create and display the form */
            java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    new Filtros().setVisible(true);
                }
            });
        }

     public void aplicaFiltros(){

            String nome = txtNome.getText().trim(),
                    categoria = cbxCategoria.getSelectedItem().toString().trim();      

            Date dataInicio = jdcDataDeInicio.getDate(),
                    dataFim = jdcDataDeFim.getDate();

            //Filtra Categoria, nome e intervalo de data (AND)
            Set<RowFilter<Object, Object>> filtrosAnd = new HashSet<>();
            String frmNome = String.format("^%s$", nome);
            filtrosAnd.add(RowFilter.regexFilter(frmNome, 1));

            if(!categoria.equals("Todas")) {
                String frmCateg = String.format("^%s$", categoria);
                filtrosAnd.add(RowFilter.regexFilter(frmCateg, 3));
            }

            filtrosAnd.add(RowFilter.dateFilter(ComparisonType.AFTER, dataInicio, 2));
            filtrosAnd.add(RowFilter.dateFilter(ComparisonType.BEFORE, dataFim, 2));
            sorter.setRowFilter(RowFilter.andFilter(filtrosAnd));

/*
            //Filtra só categoria
            Set<RowFilter<Object, Object>> filtroCateg = new HashSet<>();

            if(!categoria.equals("Todas")) {
                String frmCateg = String.format("^%s$", categoria);
                filtroCateg.add(RowFilter.regexFilter(frmCateg, 3));
            }
            sorter.setRowFilter(RowFilter.andFilter(filtroCateg));

            //Filtra só nome
            Set<RowFilter<Object, Object>> filtroId = new HashSet<>();

            frmNome = String.format("^%s$", nome);
            filtroId.add(RowFilter.regexFilter(frmNome, 1));

            sorter.setRowFilter(RowFilter.andFilter(filtroId));

            //Filtra só intervalo de data

            Set<RowFilter<Object, Object>> filtroData = new HashSet<>();

            filtroData.add(RowFilter.dateFilter(ComparisonType.AFTER, dataInicio, 2));
            filtroData.add(RowFilter.dateFilter(ComparisonType.BEFORE, dataFim, 2));

            sorter.setRowFilter(RowFilter.andFilter(filtroData));

            //Filtra nome e intervalo de data
            Set<RowFilter<Object, Object>> filtroIdData = new HashSet<>();

            frmNome = String.format("^%s$", nome);
            filtroId.add(RowFilter.regexFilter(frmNome, 1));

            filtroIdData.add(RowFilter.dateFilter(ComparisonType.AFTER, dataInicio, 2));
            filtroIdData.add(RowFilter.dateFilter(ComparisonType.BEFORE, dataFim, 2));

            sorter.setRowFilter(RowFilter.andFilter(filtroIdData));

            //Filtra categoria e nome
            Set<RowFilter<Object, Object>> filtroIdCateg = new HashSet<>();

            frmNome = String.format("^%s$", nome);
            filtroIdCateg.add(RowFilter.regexFilter(frmNome, 1));

            if(!categoria.equals("Todas")) {
                String frmCateg = String.format("^%s$", categoria);
                filtroIdCateg.add(RowFilter.regexFilter(frmCateg, 3));
            }
            sorter.setRowFilter(RowFilter.andFilter(filtroIdCateg));

            //Filtra categoria e intervalo de data
            Set<RowFilter<Object, Object>> filtroDataCateg = new HashSet<>();

            filtroDataCateg.add(RowFilter.dateFilter(ComparisonType.AFTER, dataInicio, 2));
            filtroDataCateg.add(RowFilter.dateFilter(ComparisonType.BEFORE, dataFim, 2));

            if(!categoria.equals("Todas")) {
                String frmCateg = String.format("^%s$", categoria);
                filtroDataCateg.add(RowFilter.regexFilter(frmCateg, 3));
            }
            sorter.setRowFilter(RowFilter.andFilter(filtroDataCateg)); */

        }

        // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
        private javax.swing.JButton btnFiltrar;
        private javax.swing.JButton btnFirst;
        private javax.swing.JButton btnLast;
        private javax.swing.JButton btnNext;
        private javax.swing.JButton btnPrevious;
        private javax.swing.JComboBox<String> cbxCategoria;
        private com.toedter.calendar.JDateChooser jdcDataDeFim;
        private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
        private JScrollPane jScrollPane;
        private com.toedter.calendar.JDateChooser jdcDataDeInicio;
        private javax.swing.JLabel lblCategoria;
        private javax.swing.JLabel lblDataDeFim;
        private javax.swing.JLabel lblDataDeInicio;
        private javax.swing.JTable table;
        private javax.swing.JTextField txtNome;
            private MatriculaTableModel model;
        private TableRowSorter<TableModel> sorter;
        // End of variables declaration                   
    }
```

JSONUtils

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.util.List;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;

public class JSONUtils {

    private static String strjson = null;

    private JSONUtils() {

        if (strjson == null)
            strjson = lerArquivo();
    }

    public static List<MatriculaModel> JSONtoList() {
        String str = lerArquivo();
        Type type = new TypeToken<List<MatriculaModel>>() {
        }.getType();

        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").create();      

        List<MatriculaModel> lista = gson.fromJson(str, type);

        for (MatriculaModel teste : lista) {
            System.out.println(teste.getSelecionado());
            System.out.println(teste.getNome());
            System.out.println(teste.getData());
        }
        return lista;
    }

    private static String lerArquivo() {
        String linha = "";

        try {
            FileReader arq = new FileReader("C:\\Users\\maily\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\Filtros\\src\\filtros\\dados.json");
            BufferedReader lerArq = new BufferedReader(arq);

            linha = lerArq.readLine();
            /*
             * while (linha != null) { System.out.printf(linha); linha = lerArq.readLine();
             * // lê da segunda até a última linha }
             */
            arq.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.printf("Erro na abertura do arquivo: %s.\n", e.getMessage());
        }
        // System.out.println(linha);
        return linha;
    }

}
```

MatriculaModel

```
import java.util.Date;

public class MatriculaModel {
    private boolean selecionado;
    private String nome;
    private Date data;
    private String categoria;

    public boolean getSelecionado() {
        return selecionado;
    }

    public void setSelecionado(boolean selecionado) {
        this.selecionado = selecionado;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public Date getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(Date data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public String getCategoria() {
        return categoria;
    }

    public void setCategoria(String categoria) {
        this.categoria = categoria;
    }


}
```

MatriculaTableModel

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;

public class MatriculaTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {


    private List<MatriculaModel> dados = new ArrayList<>();
    private final String[] colunas = {"Selecionar", "Nome", "Data", "Categoria"};

    public MatriculaTableModel(List<MatriculaModel> model) {
        this.dados = model;
    }


    public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
        switch (columnIndex) {
            case 0:
                return Boolean.class;
            case 2:
                return Date.class;
            default:
                return super.getColumnClass(columnIndex);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String getColumnName(int column){
        return colunas[column];
    }

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return colunas.length;
    }

    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        return dados.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int linha, int coluna) {
        switch(coluna){
            case 0:
                return dados.get(linha).getSelecionado();
            case 1:
                return dados.get(linha).getNome();
            case 2:
                return dados.get(linha).getData();
            case 3:
                return dados.get(linha).getCategoria();
        }

        return null;
    }

    public void setValueAt(Object valor, int linha, int coluna) {
        MatriculaModel tm = dados.get(linha);
        switch (coluna) {
        case 0:
            tm.setSelecionado(new Boolean((Boolean) valor));
            break;
        }
        fireTableDataChanged();
    }

    public void addRow(MatriculaModel tm) {
        this.dados.add(tm);
        this.fireTableDataChanged();    
    }

    public void removeRow(int linha){
        this.dados.remove(linha);
        this.fireTableRowsDeleted(linha, linha);
    }

    public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        return columnIndex == 0; 
    }

    public void deletarLinhas() {
        this.dados.clear();
        this.fireTableDataChanged();
    }

}
```

MatriculaTableRenderer

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer;

public class MatriculaTableRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
        super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
        switch (column) {
            case 2:
                setText(new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss").format(value));
                break;
            default:
                break;
        } 
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    protected void setValue(Object value) {
        super.setValue(value); 
    }      
}
```

dados.json

```
[{"selecionado": false, "nome": "João", "data": "23/10/2000 00:00:00", "categoria": "Fundamental"}, {"selecionado": false, "nome": "Maria", "data": "03/05/2006 00:00:00", "categoria": "Médio"}, {"selecionado": false, "nome": "Pedro", "data": "30/02/2002 00:00:00", "categoria": "Fundamental"}, {"selecionado": false, "nome": "Laura", "data": "03/07/2008 00:00:00", "categoria": "Médio"}, {"selecionado": false, "nome": "Manoel", "data": "05/11/2018 00:00:00", "categoria": "Fundamental"},{"selecionado": false, "nome": "João", "data": "23/10/2000 00:00:00", "categoria": "Fundamental"}, {"selecionado": false, "nome": "Maria", "data": "03/05/2006 00:00:00", "categoria": "Médio"}, {"selecionado": false, "nome": "Pedro", "data": "30/02/2002 00:00:00", "categoria": "Fundamental"}, {"selecionado": false, "nome": "Laura", "data": "03/07/2008 00:00:00", "categoria": "Médio"}, {"selecionado": false, "nome": "Manoel", "data": "05/11/2018 00:00:00", "categoria": "Fundamental"},{"selecionado": false, "nome": "João", "data": "23/10/2000 00:00:00", "categoria": "Fundamental"}, {"selecionado": false, "nome": "Maria", "data": "03/05/2006 00:00:00", "categoria": "Médio"}, {"selecionado": false, "nome": "Pedro", "data": "30/02/2002 00:00:00", "categoria": "Fundamental"}, {"selecionado": false, "nome": "Laura", "data": "03/07/2008 00:00:00", "categoria": "Médio"}, {"selecionado": false, "nome": "Manoel", "data": "05/11/2018 00:00:00", "categoria": "Fundamental"}]
```

Baixar libs: [JCalendar](http://www.toedter.com/download/jcalendar-1.4.zip), [Gson](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/code/gson/gson/2.8.5/gson-2.8.5.jar)

Comment: Novamente, não está claro o que é filtro or e o que deve ser filtro and, pode parecer claro pra você que fez o codigo, mas nao está claro pra quem está lendo sua pergunta. Você precisa ser mais especifica.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não precisa dessa complexidade toda, o filtro que está usando já faz isso, é só você checar os campos antes de adicioná-los, os que não forem preenchidos(estiverem null ou em branco), você não adiciona na lista `andfilters`.

Se você sempre adicionar todos os campos, o filtro sempre vai exigir que todos os campos seja preenchidos, ou vai estourar alguma exceção quando tentar aplicar os filtros e houver algum campo nulo ou não preenchido. Se passar apenas aqueles que o usuário preencher, o filtro é aplicado apenas a eles.

Veja abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Não é tão simples infelizmente. Editei a pergunta para tentar explicar melhor.

Comment: @lys acho q vc q nao está entendendo, talvez por nao ter lido a documentacao. Se quiser usar filtros separados, nao precisa de orfilter, o andfilter ja faz isso. É só não adicionar campos vazios. Mais uma vez eu reforço que nao ler a documentacao so está fazendo voce criar complexidade desnecessária para um problema simples. A solucao q vc quer nao é a solucao mais facil para este problema, o que torna sua duvida um problema XY novamente

Comment: Realmente não sei se estou entendendo. Se o usuário não quiser preencher, vai ter algum campo vazio e o and não vai funcionar.

Comment: @lys é só não passar os campos que não forem preenchidos para o filtro, simples. Veja a edição da resposta provando que é sim simples assim, não precisa de tanta complexidade lógica como essa que você sugeriu na pergunta.

Comment: E nem do tanto de coisa que implementei no código. Só preciso testar os campos antes. Agora eu entendi. Agradeço muito pela paciência para entender meu prolema e mais ainda para tentar me fazer entender a solução.

Comment: @lys sim, é bem simples, se voce nao quer aquilo no filtro, simplesmente nao adicione, não reproduzi em codigo pq vc mesma ja fez isso no seu, ao checar se o combobox está selecionado. Basta reproduzir a verificação para os demais campos, só que você agora tem que checar se ele é diferente de null ou está em branco(vazio)

Comment: Era exatamente esta simplicidade que não entrava na minha cabeça. já consegui reproduzir no código original. Agradeço mais uma vez.